# Facebook like buttons erroneously handled as one

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xfbml

I've implemented the like button on my WP blog, but for some reason some of them (not all of them) are interpreted as being the same button. If I press like, I will also like the ones that is interpreted as the same. I can't figure out why. There are several other problems with what is shared on Facebook, but I think those problems are connected to this one.

It worked great for a few days, then I started getting an error each time I pressed the like button. After fiddling with the og:type value the error disappeared, but instead now I get this strange behaviour.

My implementation is so simple, I can't really think of any causes:

```
<div class="fb-like"><fb:like href="<?php the_permalink();?>" show_faces="true" width="600" font="arial"></fb:like></div>
```

I've found that the behaviour changes depending on what og:type I define in the header section, but with no value producing the correct result.

the blog can be seen at http://blog.parkov.dk/ (in Danish, though).

Anyone has experience with this?

Comment: Yes we are experiencing this as well. Facebook seems to have changed the way it handles redirects (like 302s?). Not sure yet. See if the bug I describe here is similar and vote on it if it is: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `href` parameter and instead use the [Open Graph meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). I see that you are using them but some **required** tags are missing:

- `og:title`
- `og:url`

**IMPORTANT NOTE**:
For the homepage use `blog` as `og:type`!

Comment: Well, I actually did use og:title and og:url, but someone on a forum insisted these would CAUSE the problems, as they set the title and url for the whole page. About the href, it is the correct way to do it. You can even see in the document you pointed to, that the generator will produce an XFBML tag with a 'href' attribute

Comment: @HaroldSmith: Yes and in the page I pointed to:`og:url - The canonical, permanent URL of the page representing the entity. When you use Open Graph tags, the Like button posts a link to the og:url instead of the URL in the Like button code.` I always use this approach, and it's working just fine. Just leave the `href` empty and use the tags I suggested and then try the URL Linter

Comment: Could you perhaps show this in example? It's unclear to me exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Harold, [my website](http://www.masteringapi.com/) homepage is an example. Here the Like plugin `href` is empty, and I set the `og:url` with the link I want Facebook to grab. As for the `og:type` I've used `website` instead of `blog` because I'll be promoting my "blog" as "website" and not just a "blog". You can use `blog`.